# Display Insert statement if RadioButtonList has a selected value of "Yes", otherwise display update statement. This is not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have searched the web, as well as this forum for answers but cannot find any solution that works for my situation.

I have a RadioButtonList with a Yes or No value.

Our requirement is to display an insert statement if RadioButtonList has a value of Yes. Otherwise, display an update statement.

The following is always displaying an update statement if I switch the IF statement from Yes to No.
Any ideas what I could be wrong?

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="No"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    
  If   VetoRadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 THen
          ddlNumber.SelectedValue.ToString()
          ddlNumber.Items.Clear()
          Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
          command.Connection = sqlCon
          command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
          command.CommandText = "insert into WaterVolume(WaterSizes)values(@tsizes)"
          command.Parameters.Clear()
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tsizes", txt_watersizes.Text)
          If sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlCon.Open()
          com.ExecuteNonQuery()
          lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
          lblSuccess.Text = "Records successfully inserted"
    sqlCon.Close()
    else
            ddlNumber.SelectedValue.ToString()
        ddlNumber.Items.Clear()
        Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        com.Connection = sqlCon
        com.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        com.CommandText = "Update table2 set firstname=@firstname, lastname=@lastname where empId = @id"
        com.Parameters.Clear()
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", empID.Text)
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", txt_firstname.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", txt_lsttname.Text)
        If sqlCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then sqlCon.Open()
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
        lblSuccess.Text = "Records successfully updated"
    sqlCon.Close()
    End If
```

Comment: How about `SelectedItem.Text` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your posted RB list has a different "id" then your code.

however, I would guess that you using perhaps a update panel, or some such.

And you don't show how that code snip is to be run (button click???).

Also, don't know where the conneciton object is comming from, but do NOT attempt to make some kind of persisted conneciton object (just don't go there!!).

So, code pattern like this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    If VetoRadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

        Dim strSQL As String =
                "insert into WaterVolume (WaterSizes) values(@tsizes)"
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@tsizes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_watersizes.Text

        MyrstPN(cmdSQL)
        lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
        lblSuccess.Text = "Records successfully inserted"

    Else
        Dim strSQL As String =
                "Update table2 set firstname = @firstname,
                lastname = @lastname
                where empId = @id"

        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL)

        With cmdSQL.Parameters
            .Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = empID.Text
            .Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_firstname.Text
            .Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txt_lsttname.Text
            .Add("@tsizes", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txt_watersizes.Text
        End With
        MyrstPN(cmdSQL)

        lblSuccess.ForeColor = Color.Green
        lblSuccess.Text = "Records successfully updated"

    End If


End Sub
```

Do NOT attempt to "manage" the open/close of the connection. Let asp.net do this for you. There is a "automatic" connection pool, and it will be managed for you, and it not a performance bottle neck. In desktop land, and before .net, it was VERY good idea to create one's own connection object, and "keep" it open. this is not required in .net and asp.net

In asp.net, no, ,don't do that!!!

And our handy helper routine is this:

```
Public Sub MyrstPN(cmdSQL As SqlCommand)

    Using mycon As New SqlConnection(GetConstr)
        Using (cmdSQL)
            cmdSQL.Connection = mycon
            mycon.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Regardless of some "shorter" cleaned up code?

That RB selected index looks to be correct. I can only thus guess that there are more moving parts here, and perhaps the RB is outside of some update panel, and thus the change is not being seen.

and don't use addwith - it leaves too much up in the air the data type of the parameter.

Comment: I love this handy helper. My question is, how do you use it with multiple recordsets?

In the example above, there are two recordsets, one with IF and the other with ELSE.